# Cannot inject a singleton object into Startup's ctor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I need to inject a singleton `AppSettings` instance into my `Startup`'s constructor, in there I'll set its initial value and will be injected then into my MVC controllers to be used by those. The snippet codes as below.

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, AppSettings appSettings)
{
     Configuration = configuration;

     appSettings.cacheDirPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
     Configuration.GetValue<string>("GitLab:cache_dir_name"));
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(appSettings.cacheDirPath);
     if (!di.Exists)
     {
          di.Create();
     }
}

public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     ...
     services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>();
}
```

Unexpectedly, it throws an exception like this:

```
2020-01-13 16:35:15.0945||ERROR|App.Program|Stopped program because of exception System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'App.AppSettings' while attempting to activate 'App.Startup'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<UseStartup>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you try `services.AddSingleton(new AppSettings())` instead?

Comment: Constructor is called before `ConfigureServices`.. so `AppSettings` is not yet registered. You can register `AppSettings` in `Program.Main` or move your logic in `ConfigureServices`

Comment: @timur still doesn't work.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't realise you use it from startup constructor. Follow @Mohamed Farouk's advice

Comment: @mohamed-farouk if I move to `ConfigureServices`, then how to attach the logic result into `AppSettings` object property, so it can be used by the other controllers?

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Startup

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, AppSettings appSettings)
{
     Configuration = configuration;
}

public AppSettings AppSettings { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     AppSettings = new AppSettings();
     Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings").Bind(AppSettings); //if it is section in settings or else bind all json data
     AppSettings.cacheDirPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
     Configuration.GetValue<string>("GitLab:cache_dir_name"));
     services.AddSingleton<AppSettings>(AppSettings);
     DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(AppSettings.cacheDirPath);
     if (!di.Exists)
     {
          di.Create();
     }
}
```

> 2. Controller

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
        private readonly AppSettings  _appsettings;
        public MyController(AppSettings appsettings) {
            _appsettings = appsettings;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Method()
        {
            var setting = _appsettings.cacheDirPath;
        }
}
```